# Angular 2 error never get to custom error handler

Tags: angular, error-handling, observable

I've got the simpliest implementation of Angular's (v2.4.3) custom error handler but still can't log errors. What can be wrong?

app.module.ts

```ts
providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler }
]
```

my-error-handler.ts

```ts
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private errorHandlerService: ErrorHandlerService) {
    super();
  }

  public handleError(error: any): void {
    console.log('error'); // nothing
  }
}
```

sample-service.ts (trying to throw error)

```ts
  addSomething(data) {
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify(data);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.url + 'expense', bodyString, options)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    console.log(error.json()); // error: { message: 'Some error' }

    return Observable.throw(error.json());
  }
```

Error throwed in service never get to MyErrorHandler. What could be wrong?

I don't know if that's important but in console I also got something like this:

```ts
POST http://path/to/api 422 // logged by zone.js
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change

```
export class MyErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
```

to

```
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
```

refer to here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html

And you should also remove the `.catch` method that short-circuit the error handling

```
return this.http.post(this.url + 'expense', bodyString, options)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);      // remove this method call
```

Comment: I think that's because you have specified another handler using `.catch` method. Remove it, you should be able to see your custom error handler getting called

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you! Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: Using `extends` instead if `implements` frees you up to be able to inject custom services into you `MyErrorHandler` class, instead of using `private injector: Injector`.

Comment: Shouldn't you also be able to use extends? My understanding is extends allows you to preserve the default functionality and then add to it (which is what I'd like to know how to do).

How can I get this to work with extends?

Comment: in my case it is getting called twice, any info ?